# AJAX AND SQL Duplicate results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I Have problem, I have ajax request and php script, when I click button, results duplicate.

HTML AND JS:

```js
$("#more-news").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "/getnews.php",
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned
        data: {
            lang: lng,
            last_id: last_id,
            ids: dataN
        },
        success: function(response){

            var content = document.getElementById("responsecontainer");
            content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML+response;

            //$("#responsecontainer").html(response);
            $('#more-news').attr('data-lim', Number($('#more-news').attr('data-lim')) + 10);
            //alert(response);
        }

    });
});
```

```html
<div id="responsecontainer"></div>

            <div style="text-align: center;">
                <button id="more-news" data-lim="10" style="border:none" class="btn-type-one">
                    <span class="more"><?= $this->trans->t('More'); ?></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            


<?php
$dtTTNews = [];
foreach ($front_page_news as $item) {
$dtTTNews[] = $item['id'];
?>
<? } ?>

<script>

    var dataN = <?php echo json_encode($dtTTNews); ?>;
    var lng = '<?=$lang?>';
    var last_id = '<?=end($dtTTNews)?>';

</script>
```

PHP:

```html
$ids = $_GET['ids'];

$dtNow = new \DateTime('now');

$db->set_charset("utf8");

$news_id = abs($db->real_escape_string($_GET['last_id']));

$date_now = new \DateTime('now');

$in = join(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));
//$q = $db->query("select * count(*)

$q = $db->query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE id < "'.$news_id.'" ORDER BY date_show DESC LIMIT 3');

//$q = $db->query('SELECT id, title_ru, title_md, body_ru, body_md, is_video, thumb_ru, thumb_md, date_show,title_ru, title_md
//FROM news GROUP BY id');

$lang = (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] == 'ru') ? 'ru' : 'md';

$isHidden = false;

if($q->num_rows > 0):
    while($item = $q->fetch_assoc()):
        $dtNews = new \DateTime($item['date_show']);


        if ($dtNews > $dtNow) {
            $isHidden = true;
            break;
        }


        $qs = $db->query("SELECT * FROM news_categories WHERE news_id = " . $item['id']);
        if($qs->num_rows > 0) {
            $dd = $qs->fetch_assoc();



            $qss = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE id = " . $dd['categories_id']);
            $dd2 = $qss->fetch_assoc();


            if(in_array('Скрытые новости', $dd2) || in_array('Hidden News', $dd2)) {
                $isHidden = true;
                break;
            }

        }

        $dtShow = $dtNews->format("Y-m-d");
        //$dtShow = \Noitools\Utils::timeFromPost($item['date_show'], $lang);


        if($item['active'] == '1'):
            if($item['body_' . $lang] != ''):
                if(!$isHidden):
?>

        <div class="article-item" data-news="<?= $item['id']; ?>">
            <a href="/<?=$lang?>/news_id/<?=$item['id']?>"
               class="link-img-wrap<?= ($item['is_video']) ? ' video-icon-medium' : ''; ?>">
                <img src="/uploads/newsthumbs/760_500/<?=$item['id']?>.jpg"
                     alt="">
            </a>
            <div class="details-post">
                <i><?=$dtShow?></i>

                <a href="news_cat/<?= $dd2['id'] ?>" class="standard-hover-link"><?= $dd2['title_' . $lang] ?></a>;


            </div>
            <h3><a href="/<?=$lang?>/news_id/<?=$item['id']?>"><span
                        class="detail-title"><?=$dtShow?></span> <?= $item['title_' . $lang] ?></a></h3>
            <p class="small-text">
                <?= mb_substr(strip_tags($item['body_' . $lang]), 0, 180,
                    'utf-8') ?>
            </p>
        </div>



<?php  endif; endif; endif; endwhile; endif; ?>
```

How I Can Fix this duplicates? I think, because LIMIT 3, when I click button he load 3 same elements ..

I want when I click button more, load 3 more news

Answer (score 0):

On first glance it appears that the problem lies with you SQL statement:

```
$q = $db->query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE id < "'.$news_id.'" ORDER BY date_show DESC LIMIT 3');
```

Since you are appending the Ajax results each time, you only want to fetch news results that you haven't fetched before. By using less than, you are fetching ALL results less than $news_id, each time.

What you need to do is to window your results. In other words, you need to have a starting id and then fetch several more records. So:

```
$q = $db->query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE id > "'.$news_id.'" ORDER BY date_show DESC LIMIT 3');
```

And as long as you keep passing the new id (last_id in your javascript), as the last record fetched, it should work.

The other problem you may have is your ordering. You need to order the same way that you are comparing. If comparing by id, you need:

```
$q = $db->query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE id > "'.$news_id.'" ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 3');
```

If comparing by date then something like:

```
$q = $db->query('SELECT * FROM news WHERE date_show < "'.$date_show.'" ORDER BY date_show DESC LIMIT 3');
```

You can't mix both id and date_show. Unless you know that id and date_show are strictly in the same order.

Comment: Ok. Your problem must be with setting last_id. Is this value changing? And is this value being read in properly: $news_id = abs($db->real_escape_string($_GET['last_id']));

Comment: Yes, this value changing, but send from attr data-news-id

Comment: But have a doubts, how I Can send lastID correctly?

Comment: It looks like you're doing this correctly in the Ajax call itself. But have you debugged what you get when you use: $_GET['last_id'] ?